# Terminal to full screen and back (16.04 DT)

Tags: unity, gnome-terminal

If I switch Terminal to full screen mode and then back it doesn't restore the original position and size but instead show a window which covers the whole desktop. Is there a a way to make it work like this:

80x24 Terminal in top-right corner => Click full screen => full screen Terminal => Click full screen again => 80x24 Terminal in top-right corner

Comment: This is a known bug, to be fixed real soon now: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1521302

Comment: Now it works for me, but I have no clue why? `/var/log/apt/`tells me my compiz was never updated?

Comment: The fixed package (compiz with "20160526" in its version) is available now.

Comment: I'm still on the old version `Version: 1:0.9.12.2+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1` but it works nevertheless. Wonders never cease ;)

Comment: I have no clue how this could happen. Bugs don't disappear on their own, bugs are fixed by the developers and in case it's definitely compiz ...0526... bringing the fix. Maybe you miss some other circumstance. E.g. I just realized before updating the compiz package that unmaximize worked fine if the normal sized window was previously aligned to the bottom left corner of the desktop. So it wasn't always buggy. Nevermind...

Comment: You're right, I'm just still learning: I did an `apt-cache show compiz`, assumed that it would only show the currently installed version and missed the update further up in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My system did an unattended-upgrade and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an issue with Unity and the GNOME Terminal. I tried to recreate this issue with 4 other versions of Ubuntu (though I don't think any were using GNOME terminal) and it only does this with Unity.

This isn't really a fix for the issue but I can tell you that I installed the `xfce4-terminal` and tried it. It came out of fullscreen as a standard size window not maximized.

Not an answer but a workaround.  If this is what you would like and it works for you, you can change your default so that when you use the shortcut `CTRL + ALT + T` it will launch xfce4-terminal rather than GNOME terminal you can use the following:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

and choose the `/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper`

That will change your default terminal to the xfce one.

Comment: At any rate, Xfce terminal seems to have more features than GNOME terminal.

Comment: Please do _not_ recommend switching from `gnome-terminal` to `xfce4-terminal`! `xfce4-terminal` relies on a 5+ year old version of the VTE widget, whereas `gnome-terminal` uses a pretty recent one. The old versions lacks plenty of cool features (such as rewrap on resize, italics, true colors etc.) and contains many bugs (is very slow, scrollback is stored on disk unencrypted, few known cases of crash, a known case of permanent scrollback data corruption, few display update glitches, old escape sequences generated) and a whole lot more.

Comment: if you noticed i said ... not an answer but a workaround .. he can use this until GNOME terminal or Compiz is fixed .. I have used xfce4-terminal .. it comes stock in Xubuntu and I have never had any issues with it. It is a perfectly fine replacement that can be used until this issue is solved.

Comment: You might believe xfce4-terminal is "perfectly fine replacement". I happen to know about a hundred bugs in its terminal emulation that are fixed in gnome-terminal. I definitely recommend anyone _not_ to switch to a much older and much buggier terminal emulation software just to work around the unmaximize bug. If a workaround for unmaximize is so important, a fixed compiz package is already available from the linked bug.

Comment: OK, thanks for the Info. If there's a fix on the way, I'll just work around the problem by running a dedicated full screen terminal. The only reason I need it, is to view log files.